# DaVinci Resolve 16 - Can you embed markers as chapters into the rendered metadata?

Tags: mp4, davinci-resolve, metadata

In DaVinci Resolve 16, I see that you can edit the Metadata and that will get embedded into the mp4 container.  I also noticed that if an mp4 has embedded Chapters that Resolve doesn't recognize those as markers in the timeline.. In VLC, the chapters show up just fine however.

Is there something I'm missing in Resolve that enables that functionality? The ability to embed markers as chapters in the files container as well as recognizing said embedded chapters?

Thanks